# How do I get my iPhone backups open

Tags: iphone, backup, imac, encryption

I'm trying to extract my old iPhone's backups. I'm using the iPhone Backup Extractor, and it tells me the status of my backup is "complete and encrypted". I don't recall ever encrypting my backup so I'm wondering how is this even possible?

Does the iTunes encrypt your backup without your command?

Is there a way to unencrypt the backup?

Is there any other way of extracting your backup into actual files besides iPhone Backup Extractor? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Itunes will encrypt your backup by defualt however you can turn this off (its in the options when the device is connected)

There is a program called [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) which will allow you to view the contents of your backups and allow to export the data.